# Google Fusion Table's Info Windows with Multiple Tabs

Tags: tabs, google-fusion-tables

I created a new Google Fusion Table, my objective is to show up reviews of a person to certain places like restaurants and other establishments. My row contains several columns and it will appear better if the info window will be divided into three tabs. Is it possible to do this? I have read some articles that say that Google Fusion Tables' info window layout does not support JavaScript, and thinking of creating this multiple tab layout is difficult with this situation.

**ADD**: Here's the code of how I am retrieving data from my Google Fusion Tables:

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    query: {
        select: "col1",
        from: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    options: {
        styleId: 3,
        templateId: 3
    }
});
```

How will I use `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` to create Google Maps Markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the FusionTables default infoWindow with [InfoBubbles](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html), you can add tabs.

Note this would involve using the Google Maps API v3 to display the map (wouldn't work in the native FusionTables UI)

Comment: I tried to test infoBubbles but it seems like it has different code on retrieving my data from Google Fusion Tables. How will I do it? Please see my edited question. Thanks.